# tips with awk with changing parameters

Tags: awk

i got several pieces of code that look like:

```
for ff in `seq 3 $nlpN`;
do    
    npc1[$ff]=`awk 'NR=='$ff' {print $1}' p_walls.raw`;
    echo ${npc1[$ff]};
    npc2[$ff]=`awk 'NR=='$ff' {print $2}' p_walls.raw`;
    npc3[$ff]=`awk 'NR=='$ff' {print $3}' p_walls.raw`;
    npRs[$ff]=`awk 'NR=='$ff' {print $4}' p_walls.raw`;
    echo $ff
done
```

as You can see i'm invoking awk several times. Is there a faster way to do this, like invoking awk once and do the assignments with the changin parameters?

thanks a lot in advance!

input looks like:
...
 3.76023 0.79528 0.307771 8729.82

3.76024 0.814664 0.307849 8650.2

3.76026 0.845679 0.307978 8802.97

3.76025 0.826293 0.307897 8690.43

3.76017 0.65959 0.30722 8936.07
...

im looking for sth like:

TY

Comment: please edit your post to include some sample data (3-4 lines max) for p_walls.raw. Also what does ': TY' in your title mean? Good luck.

Comment: I removed the "TY" from the title ... I'm guessing that it meant "thank you"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does look pretty inefficient.  As written, `awk` is processing the input file in its entirety four times with every pass of the loop.  I'm also pretty sure that `cut` is completely unnecessary unless you have the `FS` environment variable set to something strange.  The following will replace the multiple `awk` runs with a single pass over the data file that stops after it finds the line.  Then you can use `cut` to extract the individual fields.

```
for ff in `seq 3 $nlpN`
do
    data=`awk 'NR=='$ff' { print $1, $2, $3, $4; exit }' p_walls.raw`
    npc1[$ff]=`echo "$data" | cut -f1 -d ' '`
    echo ${npc1[$ff]}
    npc2[$ff]=`echo "$data" | cut -f2 -d ' '`
    npc3[$ff]=`echo "$data" | cut -f3 -d ' '`
    npRs[$ff]=`echo "$data" | cut -f4 -d ' '`
    echo $ff
done
```

Note that I added an `exit` statement so that awk will exit after processing the line.  This prevents it from reading the entire file on every pass.  If all that you need to do is extract a single line from a file, then you might want to use sed instead since (IMHO) the script is easier to read and it seems to be a little faster on large files.  The following sed expression is equivalent to the awk line:

```
data=`sed -n -e "$ff p" -e "$ff q" p_walls.raw`
```

The `-n` tells sed to only output from the lines that are selected by the *script*.  In this case, the *script*, supplied as two `-e` parameters.  Each is an address followed by processing command.  Multiple commands are separated newlines in sed scripts but they can also be specified by multiple `-e` parameters with the same address.  Putting this all together, the expression `42 p` tells sed to select line `42` and run the `p` command which prints the selected pattern space (the 42nd line).  The `42 q` command tells the utility to exit after processing the 42nd line.  So, our sed expression reads the first `$ff`<sup>th</sup> lines from "p_walls.raw", prints the `$ff`<sup>th</sup> one and exits.

Comment: the cut is rly unecessary there Shawley, i had already removed that, thx for pointing it out 2 thou :)  but ill try the code u proposed many many thanks!

Comment: i need to pick the line and the column, so i guess i need awk.. not sure u can do this with sed..maybe sed ...| cut should be the option...i might try that 2  thanks a lot again for the quick feedback

Comment: reading the thread again i note that the awk is still inside the loop.. can't the have the other way around? like the for inside the awk? assume i have no memory issues

Answer (score 0):

Run `awk` a single time and process the output on each iteration separately.

```
awk "(NR > 3 && NR <= $nlpN)"' { print NR, $1, $2, $3, $4 }' p_walls.raw |
while read ff c1 c2 c3 Rs
do    
    npc1[$ff]=$c1
    echo ${npc1[$ff]};
    npc2[$ff]=$c2
    npc3[$ff]=$c3
    npRs[$ff]=$Rs
    echo $ff
done
```